# Django MongoDB Model field with unique values or null

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

I am using Djongo v1.3.6 to connect Django to MongoDB. Now I would like to have an optional field for a unique value - in my case a phone number. I thought it is possible to have null as a placeholder for accounts that do not have a phone number. However, MongoDB seems to be treating null as a unique value as well. Thus, it is not letting me insert new objects into the database once one object has `phone_number: null`

I tried to declare the index for `phone_number` as `sparse` but it does not seem to take any effect. I searched the Internet for some time now but could not find anything useful for my case.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[PHONE_VALIDATOR], max_length=17, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
...
    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            {'fields': ['phone_number'], 'sparse' : True, 'unique' : True},
        ],
    }
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue altering the index that is created by Djongo using pymongo.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient, database, collection

    collection.drop_index(index_name)
    index_name = rchop(index_name, '_1')
    
    collection.create_index(
        [(index_name, pymongo.ASCENDING)],
        partialFilterExpression = {
                index_name : { "$exists" : True, "$gt" : "0", "$type" : "string" }
            }
        )
```

Once I had altered the index, I was able to insert null values into MongoDB without sacrificing the unique check for non-null values